# CUDA 11.7 failing to install on Debian sid

Tags: debian, package-management, nvidia, dependencies, cuda

I'm trying to install CUDA 11.7 (the latest) on Debian sid using the [NVIDIA-recommended method](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Debian&target_version=11&target_type=deb_local), but am running into the following errors:

```
$ uname -a
Linux foo 5.17.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 5.17.3-1 (2022-04-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ sudo apt install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia : Depends: xorg-video-abi-24 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-23 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-20 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-10 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-8 but it is not installable or
                                      xorg-video-abi-6.0 but it is not installable
                             Depends: xserver-xorg-core (< 2:1.20.99) but 2:21.1.3-2+b1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I believe that the older `xorg`/`xserver` packages are no longer eligible installation candidates because `apt` installed a new package `xcvt` the last time I did `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.  Aside from that, there are no weird broken dependencies on my system; everything is up-to-date.

1. What is the best way to get CUDA installed at this point?  Is there a way to get it installed without downgrading a bunch of packages?  (Installing `xcvt` also resulted in a lot of x* packages being upgraded, so I'm not even sure of everything I'd have to revert or what else that might break.)
2. Is this an unintentional incompatibility between Debian/NVIDIA, and if so, should it be reported as a Debian bug, or something like that?  It's not clear to me if someone needs to release an updated package version or something like that to resolve these incompatibilities.

Comment: Please ask here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Thanks!  Resolved with a workaround at https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-11-7-failing-to-install-on-debian-sid/215474 -- tldr using the .run file to install rather than the .deb method...